# Commands Work Then Don't Work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

[image: My set up]I think there's something wrong with my Minecraft. I'm using commands in command blocks and I type my command in it works I copy the command, break the block put a put in the same command and I get an error and sometimes it even says unknown command. I'm in vanilla 1.8.4. Is there anything I can do?

`/testfor @e[name=Skeletor] {Equipment:[{},{},{},{},{id:minecraft:golden_helmet}]}`

Comment: Hi KingDarren, what's the command? Can you edit it into your question?

Comment: @Robotnik Added command but its not just that one its almost all test for commamds with data tags.

Comment: Also I used the command a few days ago and it worked fine, then it didn't work then it did now it doesn't.

Comment: Maybe there's no 'Skeletor'-Entity nearby

Comment: I made sure there was and that it was wearing a golden helmet I don't know what's wrong.

Comment: Its not just that I'm trying a test for command that tests if I'm at a x y z bug it doesn't work in a command block but does in my chat. This has got to be a bug.

Comment: OK this isn't a isolated issue ethier [link] (http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/350512-help-testfor-commandblock-comparator-not-working?page=2)

Comment: have you tried changing the name to skeleton instead of skeletor? I'm pretty sure Minecraft calls them skeletons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the redstone clock is too fast for the command block to do the command, so it treats the redstone signal as continuous. Maybe slow down the redstone clock with repeaters?

Comment: I'm wondering why this was unanswered for 3 days....